# Unity c# 3d - instantiated prefab keeps affecting additionally spawned frefabs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

In my script i have
GameObject newRoom = Instantiate(rooms[ran], newPosition, transform.rotation);
in order to prevent it from affecting the other prefabs and on the code of the spawned prefab when it sets objects setactive true or false, additionally spawned prefabs continue to have the same objects in their instance set to true or false in correlation of the previously spawned prefab.

I dont know why its like this and i would greatly appreciate assistance after much trial and error